# ASP.NET implement anchor without postback

Tags: asp.net, anchor

I'm working on an ASP.NET web app in VS2010,C#, I want to make something like this page:

```
http://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-simplyscrumptious/menu
```

when you click on food categories on left, page jumps to that category without any postback, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to move with out post back

You use the anchor `#` at the end of the same page url following with the name that you with to move.

Then inside the page you place an anhro with the name that you wish to jump like

```
<a name="MovePosition"></a>
```

So if you make a link like `http://www.site.com/catalog.aspx#MovePosition` the browser will brink the line with the `<a name="MovePosition"></a>` on top.

reference: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html

### categories menu always on the same point

If you also notice the categories on the left are stay on the same position. This can be done by many ways. In this specific page is use a script to change his location. How ever the better is to place the categories inside a div and give on this div this extra style `position:fixed;bottom:0px;` and will stick on the position that you have place it relative to his parent div.

There are many ways to keep the category menu stay on the same point. One other can be found here : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/staticmenu.htm even so is old code.

Comment: thanks! but I'm creating my foods menu on code behind, how can I create <a name="..."></a> on server side? currently I'm dynamically creating Hyperlink objects

Comment: I've created HtmlAnchor object and added it to my table:         HtmlAnchor htmlanchor = new HtmlAnchor();
    htmlanchor.HRef = "#" + myReader["FCatId"].ToString();
                    htmlanchor.InnerText = cat_name[index];         also I've added #myReader["FCatId"].ToString() at bottom of my link but it doesn't work

Comment: @Ali_dotNet you need to add the attribute[name] on your point you wish to move.

Comment: I think something is going wrong, it is my code:                     HtmlAnchor htmlanchor = new HtmlAnchor();htmlanchor.InnerText = cat_name[index];htmlanchor.Attributes.Add("name", "#" + myReader["FCatId"].ToString()); then I add this control to my table

Comment: @Ali_dotNet `htmlanchor.Attributes.Add("name", myReader["FCatId"].ToString());` with out the `#` - you add the # at the end of the url, not on attribute

Comment: thanks Aristos, it worked but my links make a postback, then bring the anchor, how can I remove postback?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet do they contain an OnClick ? attribute ?

Comment: Thanks, I think I found my problem, my links are not same as my current page URL, can it be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Just addition to the previous answer @Aristos

If on the same page, just do

```
<a href="#section1">Go to section 1</a>
```

If on another page then do

```
<a href="mypage.aspx#section1">Go to section 1 on another page</a>
```

Then define the sections with `<a name="#sectionName"></a>`

```
<a name="section1"></a>
Thi section 1
content for section 1 follows


<a name="section2"></a>
This section 2
content for section 2 follows
```