# How to avoid the postback on clicking the child nodes of treeview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-applications

I have populated my trieview and on clicking the parent node, i could load the relevant content on the page.

In my case, Parent node is name of the article and child nodes are sections of article. 
On clicking the section of article (child node), i need to bring that section on top of the page.

by using like,

```
<a href="#Section_top"></a>
```

I tried to provide this anchor as my child node value,

```
node.value =  <a href="#Section_top"></a>"
```

Now on clicking the child node, it does a postback, instead of bringing the section to top of the page.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: hope this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313592/asp-net-implement-anchor-without-postback

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to add

```
 <a href="#Section_top"></a>"
```

In the Node.Name property

Answer (score 0):

Use following :

```
 <a name="Section_top"></a>
```